# Laravel Cors - Class throttle does not exist after installing CORS package

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed a CORS package, and it seems to be working(No console errors), however I'm now getting a 500 error `Class throttle does not exist`. Which I cant get my head around. I believe it may be something to do with my Kernel.php file maybe?

Laravel Framework 5.8.5

Cors library https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors.

I have tried `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

ApiController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function generateAccessToken(Request $request)
    {

        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;



        $response = $http->post('http://social.kindle/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '1',
                'client_secret' => 'yilrEuaPympsmS4ThXx81dvnzAxwY7nQYBpbnLtr',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }

    public function post() {
        //header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

api.php

```
<?php

   Route::get('/access-token','ApiController@generateAccessToken');
   Route::post('/customer-dash/post', function (Request $request) {
      dd('test');
      //return Auth::user();
   });




   Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
      return Auth::user();
   });
```

Error Stack

```
{
    "message": "Class throttle does not exist",
    "exception": "ReflectionException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
    "line": 794,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
            "line": 794,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "ReflectionClass",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
            "line": 671,
            "function": "build",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
            "line": 619,
            "function": "resolve",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
            "line": 757,
            "function": "make",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 152,
            "function": "make",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 682,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 657,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 623,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 59,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to hit the '/customer-dash/post' URL from my front end Angular code base but thats when I get the 500 error. Can anyone help resolve the 500 error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've removed some of the middleware definitions from the `$routeMiddleware` array.

If you add the following to your `Http/Kernel.php file, the error should disappear!

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```